# Method Agent_OnLoad is called after shutdown jvm

Tags: java, javaagents, jvmti

I wrote simple agent:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, char *options, void *reserved) {    
printf("Agent start");
}
```

And simple client:

```
public class Agent {
//java -agentpath:/path_to_lib Agent

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("Main");
}}
```

And if I run program I will see the output below:

> Main
>
> Agent start

Why method main invoke before Agent_OnLoad?

Comment: Can you show how you are running it on command line? Also, add a new line to the printf in Agent_OnLoad so that the buffers get flushed. I wonder if that is causing the out-of-sequence outputs. You could also declare a static variable to indicate that the Agent_OnLoad has finished, and check it in Agent_OnUnload.

Answer (score 1):

The `Agent_OnLoad` function is being called before main during start of the VM, however the `stdout` buffer is printing after reaching the `newline`. Add a `\n` at the end of `printf` to see it working. Following answer explains it in detail:

[Why does `printf` not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Moreover, you can confirm this by putting a breakpoint on the `printf` (If you're using a debugger) to see that it'd be called at start but won't print until the buffer reaches `newline` character.